# Language converter in C++ (from japanese to english)

Tags: c++, nlp

Once again i need ur help, i have a file in japanese language and i want to convert that file into english using C++, since i dont think that i can use any API's of google in c++, so any general idea can prove helpful for me, Please suggest something.

Thanks a lot

Owais Masood

Comment: Translating between any two languages is an incredibly complicated topic, let alone two as different as Japanese and English.  You could go with a dictionary style look-up for words for a literal translation, but the results would be pretty crummy.

Comment: Does google not provide a web API for translation. It is relatively easy to connect to web service if you have the service API.

Comment: Determining whether you can use Google APIs would be tremendously easier than trying to create your own solution.  You don't need a general idea, other than to find and spend money on somebody else's product.

Answer (score 3):

You can buy a machine translation SDK and use it to translate the text. Of course, no machine translation is going to give you perfect (or even good) results.

Comment: I'll add to this:  creating something like this requires a great deal of expertise in computational linguistics (I took two classes in it at the graduate level, and I'm very far from being qualified), good knowledge of both languages, and a whole lot of testing.  The SDKs aren't necessarily cheap, but they're going to be incredibly cheaper than rolling your own.